# How many Decepticons revived Megatron?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-revenge-of-the-fallen

In *Revenge of the Fallen*, there's a scene where several Decepticons dive into the Laurentian Abyss to resurrect Megatron.

The US Navy detects 5 bogeys. 
Those 5 revive Megatron, but in the process destroy another Decepticon for parts, so the total number should stay five.

But on the way up, the Navy verbally updates their bogey count to six.

What's happening here? Am I missing something? Or is this an editing error?

I can't catch the details when I watch it. But the equation should be 5 - 1 + 1 = 5 Decepticons.

> - What do you got?
>   - SU pulled five contacts at 5,000 feet, diving fast. Never seen anything dive that deep that fast.
>   - Man battle stations.
>   - Chief of the watch, man battle stations! Helm, left full rudder, all ahead two-thirds.
>   - Left full rudder, two-thirds.
>   - Dive, go deep.
>   - The nets protecting NBE One are screaming, sir.
>   - That is 9,300 fathoms down. And no confirmed DSRVs on site?
>   - None, sir.
>   - Then, people, we've got a problem!
>   - Need parts! Kill the little one! The shard make Energon!
>   - Conn, Sonar. Now hold six contacts, and they're coming up fast!
>   - Sound collision alarm.
>   - Left hard rudder. Five hundred feet. Angel Six, we got six hostiles coming up.

The copy of the script I found here is accurate, but doesn't include who is speaking. However, I think it's mostly obvious.

Comment: It's a terrible movie with terrible continuity and a terrible script. Your logic is sound so it was very likely a mistake in the script.

Comment: @Daft Yeah, it was definitely the worst of the 4, IMO. I actually rewatched it a few weeks ago (when I thought of this question), for the first time since shortly after the DVD release. So around 4 years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having watched the scene, I see three possibilities.

## 1: They dragged the disabled Decepticon up with them

Perhaps they saw no reason to leave good parts at the bottom of the Abyss, and dragged a sizeable piece of the dismantled Decepticon with them, which may have registered as the 6th bogey.  It's hard to see what is going on amidst all the sea froth, lens flare, and quick scene cuts.

## 2: The medical bot didn't stow himself away

The medical bot came out of the chest of one of the Decepticons, but may not have have gone back inside after Megatron's resurrection.  (We don't *see* it re-enter a larger Decepticon.) Instead, he may have simply piggybacked up to the surface by gripping on to an external part of one of the larger Decepticons, and so may have registered as the 6th "contact".

## 3: Error

It could just be a careless mistake in an already shoddy script.

Comment: It definitely seems like an error, to me, after watching that clip again. We don't see any of the others after Megatron jumps up. To me, it watches as if the submarine/human scenes were filmed first, and then in post it was decided to kill the extra Decepticon and the rest of the script wasn't adjusted.

Comment: @CreationEdge : I agree with that assessment.  I wanted to give them the benefit of the doubt with my possibilities 1 and 2, but it's almost certainly just a case of sloppiness.